# Collate tab-delimited files

Tags: text-processing, join

I want to compare the information from mapping files to retrieve crosslinked information in a tab-delimited file format.

For example, one file contains

```
COG0001 882.DVU3168
COG0002 883.DvMF_2502
COG0001 1140.Synpcc7942_0645
COG0001 1148.SYNGTS_2220
```

The other file

```
COG0001 H
COG0002 E
```

The final file should contain the following information:

```
COG0001 882.DVU3168 H
COG0002 883.DvMF_2502   E
COG0001 1140.Synpcc7942_0645    H
COG0001 1148.SYNGTS_2220    H
```

**EDIT**

Coming back to my question, I would also like to print information from file 2 to file 3.

My command is:

```
awk -F $'\t' 'FNR==NR{a[$2]++;next}a[$1]''{print $0, ..... }' file2 file1 > file3
```

This would give me everything from file1 based on what is matching column 2 (file2) to column 1 (file1).

How to set so I can also print information from file 2?

Answer (score 6):

With awk you could do it like this:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2;next}{print $0, a[$1]}' file2 file1
COG0001 882.DVU3168 H
COG0002 883.DvMF_2502 E
COG0001 1140.Synpcc7942_0645 H
COG0001 1148.SYNGTS_2220 H
```

The `NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2;next}` block is run for file2, and it stores the second field in a map, using the first field as a key.

The `{print $0, a[$1]}` block is run for file1, and it prints the current line, followed by the value retrieved from the map.

If you want the data to be tab delimited (with other whitespace not delimiting the fields), you can run `awk -F'\t' ...`, and if you also want the output tab delimited, use `awk -F'\t' -v OFS='\t' ...`.

Comment: I just gave it a try and it worked. Now I just have to understand it so I can apply it for multiple files. Thanks alot you saved me!

Comment: got it..I learned to love awk :)

Comment: Coming back to my question, I would also like to print information from file 2 to file 3.

My command is:

    awk -F $'\t' 'FNR==NR{a[$2]++;next}a[$1]''{print $0, ..... }' file2 file1 > file3

This would give me everything from file1 based on what is matching column 2 (file2) to column 1 (file1).

How to set ...... so I can also print information from file 2?

Comment: @BSP What information though? Update your post with sample input/output.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind the order of output:

```
$ join <(sort file1) <(sort file2)
COG0001 1140.Synpcc7942_0645 H
COG0001 1148.SYNGTS_2220 H
COG0001 882.DVU3168 H
COG0002 883.DvMF_2502 E
```